# How to get images to the client?

Tags: node.js, express, couchdb

I'm building a website on express.js and I'm wondering where to store images. Certain 'static' website info like the team pages will be backed by a database. If new team members come onboard, we push new data to CouchDB and a new team page shows up on the site.

A team page will include a profile picture, which will be stored in CouchDB along with other data.

Should I be sending the image through the webserver or just sending the reference to where the image is and having the client grab the image from the database, since CouchDB is an HTTP server itself?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert from Couch DB, but here is my 2 cents.  In general hitting DB for every image, is going to increase the load. If the website is going to be accessed by many people, that will be a lot.

Ideal way is serve it with CDN, and have the CDN server point to your resource server/ webserver.

Comment: So, this would be great, but I serve all my site's content over SSL. I get 'not a trusted party' errors when my CDN tries to serve my website images via CNAME but without my SSL certs; rightly so.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the profile pics (and any other file) as attachments to the docs. The load is the same like for every other web-server.

Documentation:

- [attachment endpoint /db/doc/attachment](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/document/attachments.html)
- [document endpoint /db/doc](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/document/common.html%23attachments)

CouchDB manages the ETags for attachments as well as for docs or views. Clients which have cached the pics already will get a light-weight 304 response for every identical request. You can try it out with my CouchDB based blog [lbl.io](http://lbl.io). Open you favorite browser developer bar and observe the image requests during multiple refreshes.

Hint 1: If you have the choice between inline-attachment-upload (Base64 encoded in the doc, 1 request to create a doc with attachment) or upload-attachment-only (multipart/related in the original content type, 2 requests to create a doc with attachment or 1 request to create an attachment when the doc already exists) .... then choose the second. Its more efficient handled by CouchDB.

Hint 2: You can [configure CouchDB to handle gzip compression by the content-type](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/config/misc.html%23attachments) of attachments. It reduces the load a lot.

Comment: 1) What about SSL? My entire site is served over SSL.

Comment: 2) My CouchDB is not public, it's got a username and password. The client can't access images directly from CouchDB (at least not with basic auth) because I'll expose my db name and password in the src attribute.

Comment: A 1) All statements are valid for requests via SSL. I would recommend to use a HAproxy in front of CouchDB to enable SSL (CouchDBs SSL configuration can be hard to configure as Grade A security server).

Comment: A 2) As long as the user is logged in to CouchDB an authentication cookie exists which the browser will automatically send during image requests.

Comment: This is the public part of my site, so most won't be logged in.

Comment: Then these images should also be public? You can attach them to public docs or you replicate the docs with the profile attachments continuesly from all private dbs to a public db. But you can't trigger any transformation (e.g. stripping out confidential data) on docs during replication. You have to store them in the private dbs as they should appear in the public db. ... The public/private data handling of user accounts is a common problem. There is also the possibility to define public properties of user docs in the _users db. I use often a public db with user profiles to enable networking.

Comment: Be aware that on your password protected couchdb deployment you can make two db's: `production-private`, `production-public` and replicate only `production-public` to a second public-facing couchdb deployment

Comment: Thank, and yes, this is what I'm struggling with. I think, for the static website images, I'll just keep them on the web server, and store a relative path in the couchdb docs. This will work for the localhost and production servers/DBs. Later, I'll try to resolve issues with AWS S3 for user images. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I just dump avatars in `/web/images/avatars`, store the filename only in couchdb, and serve the folder with `express.static()`

You certainly can use a couchdb attachment

You can also create an amazon s3 bucket and save the absolute https path on your user objects

Comment: I'd like to use S3 for user images, so that's helpful, but I'm concerned about the SEO issues of putting S3 urls in my images src attributes. Are those not founded you think?

Comment: Also, S3 still uses SHA1, and it gives browser warnings, uggh.